# ASP.net Web API Singleton doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'v used many ways to keep an object instance alive to share it's data between request.But All the methods even dependency injection doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've realized that my App get recycled by every request and the reason was I wrote some log files in bin folder.**So if you make any change in your bin directory, IIS will recycle your application**.

Comment: Still, using state in your web API is not a best practice. Can't you use a cache or something?